# PyTorch: How do the means and stds get calculated in the Transfer Learning tutorial?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm going through the PyTorch Transfer Learning tutorial at: [link](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#visualize-a-few-images)

In the data augmentation stage, there is the following step to normalize images:

```
transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
```

I can understand why it's doing this but I can't find how the mean and std values get calculated? I tried to calculate the mean on the train data set and the mean values are:

```
array([ 0.11727478,  0.04542569, -0.28624609], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your numbers don't seem right to me; since the [ToTensor transform](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor) has output in the range [0.0, 1.0] it shouldn't be possible to get a negative mean.

If I calculate the mean with

```
traindata = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + '/train', transforms.ToTensor())
image_means = torch.stack([t.mean(1).mean(1) for t, c in traindata])
image_means.mean(0)
```

I get `(0.5143, 0.4760, 0.3487)` and for the validation set `(0.5224, 0.4799, 0.3564)`. These are closer to the numbers in the tutorial. Searching for the specific numbers, you'll see that they appear in the [Imagenet example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py), so my guess is that they are the means of the Imagenet dataset, of which the tutorial dataset is a subset.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to calculate the mean on the normalized data hence the negative mean. This makes sense now. It'll be much clearer if the author can add a line of comment in the tutorial to say why it's using those values.

Comment: Hey, I'm using this exact same logic, but for some odd reason, it gives me an error that says that a number is not in range. The number mentioned is the length of the dataset itself, which I'm guessing means that it's somehow trying to use that length as an index somehow. Do you know what would be causing this issue? @nnnmmm

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mean and standard deviation on the whole dataset by iterating all over the images. Like that

You need PyTorch and Torchvision

```
torch~=1.8.0
torchvision~=0.9.0
```

**Code**

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
    root='/Path/',
    transform=transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
)

loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=1, num_workers=4)
print(loader)
data = next(iter(loader))
print("Mean", data[0].mean())
print("Std",  data[0].std())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_mean_std(loader):
    mean = 0.
    std = 0.
    for images, _ in loader:
        batch_samples = images.size(0) # batch size (the last batch can have smaller size!)
        images = images.view(batch_samples, images.size(1), -1)
        mean += images.mean(2).sum(0)
        std += images.std(2).sum(0)

    mean /= len(loader.dataset)
    std /= len(loader.dataset)
    return mean, std
```